# How to get a java.time object from a java.sql.Timestamp without a JDBC 4.2 driver?

Tags: java, datetime, jdbc, java-time

When retrieving a [java.sql.Timestamp](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) from a database via JDBC 4.1 or earlier, how does one obtain/convert to a [java.time](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) object?

Neither of the open-source JDBC drivers for Postgres is JDBC 4.2 compliant yet, so I'm looking for a way to use use java.time with JDBC 4.1.

Comment: May I ask why you need to use java.time, that appear to be new 1.8 classes?

Comment: Because java.util.Date & .Calendar are notoriously troublesome. I usually use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/‎) instead. But I've been dabbling with java.time in Java 8. The java.time package is inspired by Joda-Time but is re-architected.

Comment: **UPDATE:** While I accepted [the Answer by pickypg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22470650/642706) as correctly addressing the specifics of my Question, the best solution is to use only the *java.time* classes with JDBC 4.2 while avoiding entirely the troublesome legacy *java.sql* classes. Exchange *java.time* objects directly with the database; no need for conversion anymore. See the [Answer by skrueger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668272/642706).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## New Methods On Old Classes

By using the driver with Java 8 and later, you should automatically pick up some methods on your [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.java.net/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object for free. Both [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) and [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) have similar conversion methods.

Namely, to convert from *java.sql* to *java.time* you are looking for:

- [`Timestamp::toInstant()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant--)
- [`Timestamp::toLocalDateTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime--)
- [`Date::toLocalDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--)
- [`Time::toLocalTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#toLocalTime--)

To go the other direction, from *java.time* to *java.sql*, use the new static methods:

- [`Timestamp.from(instant)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-)
- [`Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDateTime-)
- [`Date.valueOf(localDate)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDate-)
- [`Time.valueOf(localTime)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalTime-)

Example:

```java
preparedStatement.setTimestamp( 2, Timestamp.from(instant) );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the insight. I was focused on the JDBC driver, and did not think to look at the `java.sql.Timestamp` class’ new features.

Comment: FYI, after getting an `Instant` as seen in this Answer, you can apply a [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or better, apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). For more info, see [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36639155/642706) and [my diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5yzFN.png) on another Question.

Comment: Upcoming release should have support for java 8 time API: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html

Comment: When using a column of type TIMESTAMP (without time-zone, which I see as equivalent to a LocalDateTime) what time-zone will JDBC use to convert that TIMESTAMP to an instant?

Comment: If you're storing timestamps into a database, you should be storing them as UTC. Otherwise, I think that you are right. See this [`setTimestamp` answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14070771/706724).

Comment: The example given, at least when using the Microsoft JDBC implementation, causes the *local datetime of the JVM* to be written to the DB, not a datetime in UTC.  There is an override on the setTimestamp() method that takes a Calendar instance, so you can provide the timezone you want.

Comment: This is dangerous advice. `Timestamp` is fundamentally `Instant` like (no timezone, UTC-epoch-millis based), and therefore, if the database is actually storing e.g. TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, which is more like ZonedDateTime, you're converting from ZDT to instant on one side and then letting j.s.Timestamp convert back to ZDT which __easily risks introducing errors due to mismatching zones__. It's also slow. Much, much, MUCH better: `rs.getObject(index/colName, LocalDateTime.class)`. Which avoids all that dangerous conversion. Replace LDT with whatever type you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

## No need to convert

Like others have said in comments, PostgreSQL's JDBC driver now supports JDBC 4.2 including Java 8 Time API support. We can exchange *java.time* objects directly with the database.

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html

So no need to convert, no need to ever use the java.sql types again. Use only their replacements in the *java.time* package as shown in this list.

```
PostgreSQL™                      Java SE 8 (java.time)
DATE                             LocalDate
TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]        LocalTime
TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]   LocalDateTime
TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE          OffsetDateTime or Instant
```

This can be retrieved via `ResultSet::getObject`

```
ResultSet rs = ...;
while (rs.next()) {
  LocalDate localDate = rs.getObject(1, LocalDate.class));
}
```

Store a *java.time* object by calling `PreparedStatement::setObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myInstant ) ;
```

Comment: This Answer is a very important update. Sticking with the *java.time* classes only is indeed the way to go.