# No. of days between two timestamps

Tags: java, timestamp, days

I have two timestamp values. like

```
Timestamp date1;
    Timestamp date2;
```

Now I want to find no. of days between these two timeStamps like in java

```
int no_of_days = difference(date2 - date1)
```

the above codes are just for clarification of the question. just ignore the coding mistakes.

Comment: Do you mean multiples of 24 hours? Do you mean how many dates in a given timezone? e.g. 2018/12/26 23:00 to  2018/12/27 01:00 is 0, 1 or 2 days?

Comment: what version of Java are you using, as this can have an impact on the answer.

Comment: yes @PeterLawrey...

Comment: I am using Java 8

Comment: So which one? they are all different options.

Comment: 1 day @PeterLawrey

Comment: Do you know which timezone you want to perform the calculation in? These times are on the same day in some time zones, and different days in others.

Comment: The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed and long outdated, you don’t need it in 2018. You can probably use `Instant` from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) otherwise some other type from this API. For your own sake and for those seeing your code after you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Duration` for this (it works for java 8) :

```
Duration between = Duration.between(date1.toInstant(), date2.toInstant());

int no_of_days = between.get(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8, it will be much easier. Here's a one way of doing it.

```
Duration.between(date1.toLocalDateTime(), date2.toLocalDateTime()).toDays();
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers given here so far only handle a day unit as fixed amount of 24 hours by using the class `java.time.Duration`. If you consider your timestamps in the context of daylight saving switching time zones then this is probably not what you want.

During the change from winter to summer time, a calendar day can last only 23 hours (or even 23:30 in some rare cases). And in autumn when switching back to winter time, the calendar days can be more than 24 hours long. So **you also need a time zone** to handle this situation in order to calculate durations in the correct way.

**Suggested solution if your timestamps have been stored in the database coming from instants:**

```
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = date2.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long days = java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(zdt1, zdt2);
```

Of course, you are free to specify any other zone than the system time zone. The result can vary depending on the chosen zone.

**Suggested solution if your timestamps have been stored coming from `LocalDateTime` without any zone context:**

```
LocalDateTime ldt1 = date1.toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime ldt2 = date2.toLocalDateTime();
long days = java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ldt1, ldt2);
```

Here I still prefer the enum `ChronoUnit.DAYS` because the type `java.time.Duration` internally stores seconds and nanoseconds only and is hence rather designed for machine-like timestamps. And another remark: The second solution implicitly uses your system time zone for the conversion from `java.sql.Timestamp` to `LocalDateTime`. This is only correct if you also have stored your timestamps that way.

By the way, **with a JDBC-4.2-compliant driver**, you could also [retrieve your `java.time`-type directly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-), see also a [related post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668272/2491410).